# Let $F(x)=cot\int_{\int_{0}^{x}tan(a)da}^{1}cosh(\int_{0}^{t}udu)dt$ Find $F'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

"Let $F(x)=\cot\int_{\int_{0}^{x}\tan(a)da}^{1}\cosh(\int_{0}^{t}udu)dt$. Find $F'(x).$"

We know:

$F'(x)=-\csc^{2}(\int_{\int_{0}^{x}\tan(a)da}^{1}\cosh(\int_{0}^{t}udu)dt)\times(\int_{\int_{0}^{x}\tan(a)da}^{1}\cosh(\int_{0}^{t}udu)dt)'$

Let $A(x)=\int_{\int_{0}^{x}\tan(a)da}^{1}\cosh(\int_{0}^{t}udu)dt$

Then: $A'(x)=-\cosh(\int_{0}^{\int_{0}^{x}\tan(a)da}udu)\tan(x)$

Then,

$F'(x)=\csc^{2}(\int_{\int_{0}^{x}\tan(a)da}^{1}\cosh(\int_{0}^{t}udu)dt)\cosh(\int_{0}^{\int_{0}^{x}\tan(a)da}udu)\tan(x)$

But I'm not sure my result is correct. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi OP! I've looked your answer over and I believe it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has the form

$$F (x)=\cot (f (x))=$$
$$\cot (-\int_1^{g (x)}h (t)dt )$$

with $$g (x)=\int_0^x\tan (a)da $$
and
$$h (t)=\cosh (\int_0^t udu) .$$

thus

$$F'(x)=-\frac {1}{\sin^2 (f (x))}\Bigl (-h (g (x))g'(x)\Bigr) $$

with $$g'(x)=\tan (x) $$

hence

> $$F'(x)=(1+F^2 (x))\cosh (\int_0^{\int_0^x\tan (a)da})\tan (x) $$

Comment: It looks to me like your answer and the OP's agree. (You seem to have cancelling minus signs that the OP doesn't.)

Comment: @Chris is this final expression correct.

Comment: Well yes, since $1 + \cot^2(x) = \csc^2(x)$, but I'd just leave it as $F'(x) = \csc^2(f(x))\cdots$.